# Is there a way to tell apt about a manually installed program?

Tags: apt, package-management

Here's my basic issue:

```
£ apt show cmake | grep -i version
Version: 3.5.1-1ubuntu3
£ apt show debhelper | grep -i breaks
Breaks: cmake (<< 3.9~), dh-systemd (<< 1.38), meson (<< 0.40.0~)
£ cmake --version
cmake version 3.11.20180516-gacb971
£
```

`cmake` was built and installed from source.  I can't uninstall the apt version because many packages depend on it.  The `debhelper` package is from a neovim ppa (16.04), and is honestly probably broken for 16.04 (breaking cmake<3.9 on a 16.04 system doesn't make sense), but...it's actually not an issue on my system.  But of course apt refuses to install it.

Is there a way to tell apt what my cmake version actually is?  Of course, `cmake 3.11` is *not* an apt package and could be missing things, so I doubt it.  If not, what might be a good solution to this problem?

Comment: I like that British prompt, `£` :-)

Comment: @PerlDuck - funny you should say that.  I logged into a coworker's tmux session today and wrote `$ #your dollar sign prompt is so....pedestrian`